# Improve the time computation of an ODE solving

Tags: python, performance

I have an ODE to solve which is FitzHugh Nagumo equations for heart cell modeling. I made a code which uses the Euler method to solve two ODEs. So I have this :

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass
from numba import int32, float64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

spec = [('V_init' ,float64),
        ('a' ,float64),
        ('b' ,float64),
        ('g',float64),
        ('dt' ,float64),
        ('NbODEs',int32),
        ('dydx' ,float64[:]),
        ('y'    ,float64[:]) ]

@jitclass(spec, )
class FHNfunc:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.V_init = .04
        self.a= 0.25
        self.b=0.001
        self.g = 0.003
        self.dt = .01
        self.NbODEs = 2
        self.dydx    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs, )
        self.y    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs, )

    def Eul(self):
        self.deriv()
        self.y += (self.dydx * self.dt)

    def deriv(self , ):
        self.dydx[0]= self.V_init - self.y[0] *(self.a-(self.y[0]))*(1-(self.y[0]))-self.y[1]
        self.dydx[1]= self.b * self.y[0] - self.g * self.y[1]
        return


FH = FHNfunc()
dt = .001
tp = np.linspace(0, 1000, num = int((1000)/dt))

V = np.zeros(len(tp), )
W = np.zeros(len(tp), )

t0 = time.time()
for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
    FH.Eul()
    V[idx] = FH.y[0]
    W[idx] = FH.y[1]

print(time.time()- t0)

plt.subplots()
plt.plot(tp,V)
plt.plot(tp,W)
plt.show()
```

What I tried is use the `numba jitclass` in order to improve the time performence of the FHN ODEs solving, but it is not that helpful I would expect it to be.
For that example, the code gives me 11.44s without jitclass use (when I comment `@jitclass(spec, )`) and 6.14s with jitclass use. I'm not complaining about gaining twice the computation time, but I expected more. I know I could integrate the for loop inside the class but I need it to be outside.
So I'm seeking for solution to improve even more the computation time for this exemple.

Edit: I tried to implement ODE function outside the class with jit this time:

```
__author__ = 'Maxime'
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass, jit
from numba import int32, float64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

spec = [('V_init' ,float64),
        ('a' ,float64),
        ('b' ,float64),
        ('g',float64),
        ('dt' ,float64),
        ('NbODEs',int32),
        ('dydx' ,float64[:]),
        ('time' ,float64[:]),
        ('V' ,float64[:]),
        ('W' ,float64[:]),
        ('y'    ,float64[:]) ]

# @jitclass(spec, )
class FHNfunc:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.V_init = .04
        self.a= 0.25
        self.b=0.001
        self.g = 0.003
        self.dt = .001
        self.NbODEs = 2
        self.dydx    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs  )
        self.y    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs  )

    def Eul(self):
        self.deriv()
        self.y += (self.dydx * self.dt)


    def deriv(self):
        # self.dydx[0]= self.V_init - self.y[0] *(self.a-(self.y[0]))*(1-(self.y[0]))-self.y[1]
        # self.dydx[1]= self.b * self.y[0] - self.g * self.y[1]
        self.dydx[0]= fV(self.V_init,self.y[0],self.y[1],self.a)
        self.dydx[1]= fW(self.y[0],self.y[1],self.b,self.g)
        return


@jit(float64(float64, float64, float64, float64))
def fV(V_init,y0,y1,a):
    return V_init - y0 *(a-(y0))*(1-(y0))-y1


@jit(float64(float64, float64, float64, float64))
def fW(y0,y1,b,g):
    return b * y0 - g * y1


FH = FHNfunc()
dt = .001
tp = np.linspace(0, 1000, num = int((1000)/dt))

V = np.zeros(len(tp), )
W = np.zeros(len(tp), )

t0 = time.time()
for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
    FH.Eul()
    V[idx] = FH.y[0]
    W[idx] = FH.y[1]
print(time.time()- t0)
plt.subplots()
plt.plot(tp,V)
plt.plot(tp,W)
plt.show()
```

But In this case I got no time improvment at all: 11.4s.

### Why I cannot have the integral loop inside the class

When I have several models and I want a coupling between them, I need to pass variable between FHN instances. For instance:

```
__author__ = 'Maxime'
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass, jit, njit
from numba import int32, float64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

spec = [('V_init' ,float64),
        ('a' ,float64),
        ('b' ,float64),
        ('g',float64),
        ('dt' ,float64),
        ('NbODEs',int32),
        ('dydx' ,float64[:]),
        ('time' ,float64[:]),
        ('V' ,float64[:]),
        ('W' ,float64[:]),
        ('y'    ,float64[:]) ]

@jitclass(spec, )
class FHNfunc:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.V_init = .04
        self.a= 0.25
        self.b=0.001
        self.g = 0.003
        self.dt = .001
        self.NbODEs = 2
        self.dydx    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs  )
        self.y    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs  )


    def Eul(self):
        self.deriv()
        self.y += (self.dydx * self.dt)


    def deriv(self):
        self.dydx[0]= self.V_init - self.y[0] *(self.a-(self.y[0]))*(1-(self.y[0]))-self.y[1]
        self.dydx[1]= self.b * self.y[0] - self.g * self.y[1] 
        return



FH1 = FHNfunc()
FH2 = FHNfunc()
FH2.V_init=0.
dt = .001
tp = np.linspace(0, 1000, num = int((1000)/dt))

V1 = np.zeros(len(tp), )
V2 = np.zeros(len(tp), )
W1 = np.zeros(len(tp), )
W2 = np.zeros(len(tp), )

t0 = time.time()
for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
    FH1.Eul()
    FH2.V_init=FH1.V_init
    FH2.Eul()
    V1[idx] = FH1.y[0]
    W1[idx] = FH1.y[1]
    V2[idx] = FH2.y[0]
    W2[idx] = FH2.y[1]

print(time.time()- t0)
plt.figure
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(tp,V1)
plt.plot(tp,W1)
plt.subplot(212)
plt.plot(tp,V2)
plt.plot(tp,W2)
plt.show()
```

In this case I don't know how to use numpy with the variable passing between instances. Also, for this exemple, all nstances are of the same class but in my complete model, I have 8 differents classes to represent different kinds of model in belonging to the system.

### Answer of @max9111

So I tested it with the njit with two neurons connected together and that work pretty good:

```
__author__ = 'Maxime'
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass, jit, njit
from numba import int32, float64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

spec = [('V_init' ,float64),
        ('a' ,float64),
        ('b' ,float64),
        ('g',float64),
        ('dt' ,float64),
        ('NbODEs',int32),
        ('dydx' ,float64[:]),
        ('time' ,float64[:]),
        ('V' ,float64[:]),
        ('W' ,float64[:]),
        ('y'    ,float64[:]) ]

@jitclass(spec, )
class FHNfunc:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.V_init = .04
        self.a= 0.25
        self.b=0.001
        self.g = 0.003
        self.dt = .001
        self.NbODEs = 2
        self.dydx    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs  )
        self.y    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs  )

    def Eul(self,):
        self.deriv()
        self.y += (self.dydx * self.dt) 

    def deriv(self,):
        self.dydx[0]= self.V_init - self.y[0] *(self.a-(self.y[0]))*(1-(self.y[0]))-self.y[1]
        self.dydx[1]= self.b * self.y[0] - self.g * self.y[1] 
        return


@njit(fastmath=True)
def solve2(FH1,FH2,tp):
    V1 = np.zeros(len(tp), )
    V2 = np.zeros(len(tp), )
    W1 = np.zeros(len(tp), )
    W2 = np.zeros(len(tp), )

    for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
        FH1.Eul()
        FH2.V_init=FH1.V_init
        FH2.Eul()
        V1[idx] = FH1.y[0]
        W1[idx] = FH1.y[1]
        V2[idx] = FH2.y[0]
        W2[idx] = FH2.y[1]

    return V1,W1,V2,W2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #with njit and jiclass
    FH1 = FHNfunc()
    FH2 = FHNfunc()
    FH2.V_init=0.
    dt = .001
    tp = np.linspace(0, 1000, num = int((1000)/dt))

    t0 = time.time()
    [V1,W1,V2,W2] = solve2(FH1,FH2,tp)
    print(time.time()- t0)
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(tp,V1)
    plt.plot(tp,W1)
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot(tp,V2)
    plt.plot(tp,W2) 

    #with jitclass only
    FH1 = FHNfunc()
    FH2 = FHNfunc()
    FH2.V_init=0.
    dt = .001
    tp = np.linspace(0, 1000, num = int((1000)/dt))

    t0 = time.time()
    V1 = np.zeros(len(tp), )
    V2 = np.zeros(len(tp), )
    W1 = np.zeros(len(tp), )
    W2 = np.zeros(len(tp), )

    for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
        FH1.Eul()
        FH2.V_init=FH1.V_init
        FH2.Eul()
        V1[idx] = FH1.y[0]
        W1[idx] = FH1.y[1]
        V2[idx] = FH2.y[0]
        W2[idx] = FH2.y[1]
    print(time.time()- t0)
    plt.figure()
    plt.subplot(211)
    plt.plot(tp,V1)
    plt.plot(tp,W1)
    plt.subplot(212)
    plt.plot(tp,V2)
    plt.plot(tp,W2)
    plt.show()
```

with this I have 1.8 s with all optimization (njit & jitclass) with two instances of the model. I have 12.4s with the jitclass only and 21.7s with no numba at all. So a factor of 12, not bad at all.
Thanks to @max9111 for the solution.

Comment: Jitclasses are a quite new feature. When I tried it on another example, the jitclass approuch was outperfomed by quite a margin by using only functions. Maybe it is worth a try to write the same algorithm without jitclass

Comment: That's not a minimal, complete and verifiable example mainly because it is far from minimal.

Comment: Why are you saying that? It is two small equations. Why this is not minimal, complete and verifiable example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is all about function inlining and LLVM optimization**

All functions are really primitive (regarding the computation time). So the only thing numba can do here is inlining this functions and cache the compiled functions to avoid compilation overhead on the next calls.

Your Jitclass Benchmark has one main problem. You are calling a primitive function from non compiled code 1000000 times. (meaning 1000000 function calls at least). This should look like:

**Example_1 using Jitclass**

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jitclass,njit
from numba import int32, float64
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

spec = [('V_init' ,float64),
        ('a' ,float64),
        ('b' ,float64),
        ('g',float64),
        ('dt' ,float64),
        ('NbODEs',int32),
        ('dydx' ,float64[:]),
        ('y'    ,float64[:]) ]

@jitclass(spec)
class FHNfunc:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.V_init = .04
        self.a= 0.25
        self.b=0.001
        self.g = 0.003
        self.dt = .001
        self.NbODEs = 2
        self.dydx    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs, )
        self.y    =np.zeros(self.NbODEs, )

    def Eul(self):
        self.deriv()
        self.y += (self.dydx * self.dt)

    def deriv(self , ):
        self.dydx[0]= self.V_init - self.y[0] *(self.a-(self.y[0]))*(1-(self.y[0]))-self.y[1]
        self.dydx[1]= self.b * self.y[0] - self.g * self.y[1]
        return

@njit(fastmath=True)
def solve(FH,dt,tp):
  V = np.zeros(len(tp), )
  W = np.zeros(len(tp), )

  for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
      FH.Eul()
      V[idx] = FH.y[0]
      W[idx] = FH.y[1]

  return V,W

if __name__ == "__main__":
  FH = FHNfunc()
  dt = .001
  tp = np.linspace(0, 1000, num = int((1000)/dt))

  t1=time.time()
  [V,W]=solve(FH,dt,tp)
  print(time.time()-t1)

  plt.subplots()
  plt.plot(tp,V)
  plt.plot(tp,W)
  plt.show()
```

This gives a runtime of about 0.4s.

**Example_2 and 3**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,cache=True)
def Eul(V_init,y,a,g,dt,dydx):
  deriv(V_init,y,a,b,g,dydx)
  y += (dydx * dt)

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,cache=True)
def deriv(V_init,y,a,b,g,dydx):
  dydx[0]= fV(V_init,y[0],y[1],a)
  dydx[1]= fW(y[0],y[1],b,g)

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,cache=True)
def fV(V_init,y0,y1,a):
  return V_init - y0 *(a-(y0))*(1-(y0))-y1

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,cache=True)
def fW(y0,y1,b,g):
  return b * y0 - g * y1

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,cache=True)
def solving_1(V_init,y,a,g,dt,tp):
  V = np.empty(tp.shape[0],dtype=y.dtype)
  W = np.empty(tp.shape[0],dtype=y.dtype)
  dydx=np.empty(2,dtype=np.float64)

  for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
    Eul(V_init,y,a,g,dt,dydx)
    V[idx] = y[0]
    W[idx] = y[1]

  return V,W

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,cache=True)
def solving_2(V_init,y,a,g,dt,tp):
  V = np.empty(tp.shape[0],dtype=y.dtype)
  W = np.empty(tp.shape[0],dtype=y.dtype)
  dydx=np.empty(2,dtype=y.dtype)

  for idx, t in enumerate(tp):
    dydx[0]=V_init - y[0] *(a-(y[0]))*(1-(y[0]))-y[1]
    dydx[1]=b * y[0] - g * y[1]
    y[0] += (dydx[0] * dt)
    y[1] += (dydx[1] * dt)

    V[idx] = y[0]
    W[idx] = y[1]

  return V,W

if __name__ == "__main__":
  V_init = .04
  a= 0.25
  b=0.001
  g = 0.003
  dt = .001
  dt = .001
  tp = np.linspace(0, 1000, num = int((1000)/dt))

  y=np.zeros(2,dtype=np.float64)

  t1=time.time()
  [V,W]=solving_2(V_init,y,a,g,dt,tp)
  print(time.time()-t1)

  plt.subplots()
  plt.plot(tp,V)
  plt.plot(tp,W)
  plt.show()
```

I have tested two variants here. All the work in one function and splitted to serveral function. This gives 0.17s for solving_1 and 0.06s for solving_2.

I wasn't really suprised, that the jitclass approuch is somewhat slower (caching not supported, quite new feature), but I didn't expect to see a factor two in performance in the methods solving_1 and solving_2, which are even bigger if someone uses some memory copying, which is also not optimized away.

Comment: Thks for the answer. However, I think I cannot use numba to do the integral loop. I add an update in my question if you want to look at. A wasn't aware of the `njit(fastmath` I will check it out.

Comment: The fastmath is important when it comes to simd-vectorization. amongst other things it loosens the precision requirements a bit, which can lead to better optimized code. Take a look at https://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#fast-math-flags